# Program crashes because of realloc

Tags: c++, stack, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

I am trying to build a stack that resizes itself and `realloc()` crashes my program.

Constructor:

```
Stack::Stack()
{
   st = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
   sp = 0;
   length = 1;
}
```

This is my `add()` function:

```
void Stack::add(int item)
{
   if (sp == length)
       Stack::resizeStack(&st, &length, 1);
   st[sp++] = item;
}
```

Resize function (I use the variable a in order to be able to reuse it for pop) :

```
void Stack::resizeStack(int **st, int *length, bool a)
{
   if (a == 1)
       *length *= 2;
   else
       *length /= 2;
   realloc(*st, sizeof(int) * (*length));
}
```

This is how I test my stack:

```
Stack* myStack = new Stack();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
    myStack->add(i);
    cout << myStack->getStackSize() << '\n';
}
free(myStack);
```

I have noticed that the program crashes at the end of the `for`.

I would appreciate if someone explained what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I need to ask.  Why are you using `malloc`, `free` and `realloc` in a C++ program?

Comment: Two issues: You do not maintain length and you use realloc wrong

Comment: You're deallocating `new`ed stuff with `free`, but you didn't need `new` in the first place.

Comment: In addition, you are mixing up using `new` and `free`.  `Stack *myStack = new Stack(); ... free(myStack);`  This is undefined behavior.  Seems like you're learning C++ from C books and/or tutorials.

Comment: I used the combination 'new' & 'free' just for the object. I did not even realised that. Nevertheless, it crashes even if I comment the line or use 'delete' instead. @Dieter Lücking I maintain the length in 'length' and could you please tell me what is the correct way to use realloc?

Comment: @RazvanMeriniuc Since the reallocation routine is inside your class, and your stack class actually keeps track of its current size, why not manipulate `this->length` and `this->st` directly. Then you can remove some stars. Also, why shrink the size. Usually, a dynamic array just grows, but it may have a *shrink_to_fit* method that can be called manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All those people who say, `malloc()` and `free()` are a bad idea in C++ are 100% correct. Prefer `new` and `delete` over `malloc()` and `free()` and prefer standard library containers over your own homebrew stack implementation.

Anyway, the real issue here is, that `realloc()` might allocate a new memory block and free the old one. It returns a pointer to the new one.

The correct call is:

```
*st = realloc(*st, sizeof(int) * (*length));
```

Now `*st` will store the new pointer and everything is all right.

Consider to use the standard library, instead of implementing your own fundamental data structures. It has a well designed interface, and is very thoroughly tested.

Comment: I am implementing this in order to learn both C++ and data structures. I din't realise I used free on my object. Nevertheless, the realloc was the one causing the problem. It worked the way you said. I have misunderstood how it works. The reason I used malloc() and realloc() is that I did not find a way of reallocating the memory with new. Thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 4):

You are lucky that you get a crash. This is undefined behavior.

Let's see what Bjarne Stroustrup says about this from [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#realloc):

> No, in the sense that you cannot allocate an object with malloc() and
> free it using delete. Nor can you allocate with new and delete with
> free() or use realloc() on an array allocated by new.
>
> The C++ operators new and delete guarantee proper construction and
> destruction; where constructors or destructors need to be invoked,
> they are. The C-style functions malloc(), calloc(), free(), and
> realloc() doesn't ensure that. **Furthermore, there is no guarantee that
> the mechanism used by new and delete to acquire and release raw memory
> is compatible with malloc() and free(). If mixing styles works on your
> system, you were simply "lucky"** - for now.

C++ FAQ has also special entry for this:

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/freestore-mgmt#realloc-and-renew

Answer (score 2):

Crashing at the end is most likely because you're mixing `new` with `free`. This is undefined behaviour. It may work on some systems, but is never a good idea. You should pair `new` with `delete`. Calls to `malloc` are paired with `free`, but these are more for C code. C++ code usually uses `new` and `delete`.

Of course you can eliminate the `new` by making `myStack` a local variable:

```
Stack myStack;
```

You would also need to adjust member access to use `.` instead of `->`. There would be no need to delete myStack, since local variables would be automatically cleaned up once the function exits, including in the case of exceptions.

Also noticed the return value of `realloc` is ignored. If the current memory block can't be extended by `realloc`, it must allocate a new memory block and copy the old data over to it. A new pointer is returned in this case, so `st` must be updated.

```
*st = realloc(*st, sizeof(int) * (*length));
```

But again, using `malloc`, `realloc`, and `free` is a bit odd in C++ code.

You can use `new[]` and `delete[]` if you're forced to use manual memory management of arrays (such as for learning), or you can use the `vector` or `stack` classes for more serious code.

Comment: C++ code would be embarassed to see `new` and `delete`. Use `std::vector` or bust.

Comment: @Puppy: Do any mainstream `std::vector` implementations employ `realloc`?

Comment: @Daniel Stevens Thank you for your feedback. The problem was my realloc. I did not know how to reallocate memory with new or delete, that's why I used those functions.

Comment: I have no idea, it's a meaningless implementation detail.

Comment: I believe simple realloc like functionality is purposefully missing from C++, since it may not be safe with certain data types. Consider an object with an internal pointer back into itself. If it was moved in memory with a bit-copy by a realloc, it's internal pointer would now point to its previous memory, which would be incorrect. Instead an object can be moved by being copy constructed to a new memory location, and destructed at the old location.

Comment: @DanielStevens Thank you for your explanation! The self-pointer makes sense.

Answer (score -2):

Use `std::vector` and it will automatically take care of all the memory management for you. In fact, you pretty much just don't need a Stack class in the face of `std::stack` but that's another matter.

Furthermore for the test do not allocate the Stack dynamically in a super pointless way, just make a local Stack.

Comment: This is a comment at best.

Comment: I would guess that this is for an assignment or learning exercise that has the student building an array based stack class.